# Tags for cryptographic algorithms and standards

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags

I've had a look at some tags related for cryptographic algorithms. Here are several related minor issues. We should decide on which tag names we prefer, then retag or synonymize as desired.

#### Ciphers

- **3DES**: [tripledes](/questions/tagged/tripledes) should be a synonym of [3des](/questions/tagged/3des) (the latter has a lot more uses and a tag wiki).
- **Rijndael/AES**: Should [rijndael](/questions/tagged/rijndael) be a synonym of [aes](/questions/tagged/aes)? Strictly speaking, Rijndael is a superfamily of AES, but in practice they are used almost interchangeably.
- **chaining**: We have [ecb](/questions/tagged/ecb) and [cbc-mode](/questions/tagged/cbc-mode). Which naming form is better?

#### Digests

- **`md5_file`**: Is it worth having a separate tag for [md5-file](/questions/tagged/md5-file), and if so, should it be reserved for the `md5_file` function in PHP?
- **SHA1 or SHA-1**: We have both [sha-1](/questions/tagged/sha-1) and [sha1](/questions/tagged/sha1). They should be merged, in which direction? Ditto for [sha-512](/questions/tagged/sha-512) and [sha512](/questions/tagged/sha512).
- **SHA-2**: We have separate tags for [sha2](/questions/tagged/sha2), [sha256](/questions/tagged/sha256) and [sha512](/questions/tagged/sha512). Should they be folded into [sha-2](/questions/tagged/sha-2), or should they remaine separate?

**[hmacsha1](/questions/tagged/hmacsha1)**: Should [hmacsha1](/questions/tagged/hmacsha1) remain, or should it be transformed to [hmac](/questions/tagged/hmac)+[sha-1](/questions/tagged/sha-1)?

#### PKCS

See [Merge tags: [pkcs11] and [pkcs#11]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271493/merge-tags-pkcs11-and-pkcs11)

Comment: I'm going to vote no on Rijndael synonymized with AES. While in practice, yes, they are used similarly, it would make it impossible to ask a question that *is* specific to either one, like "Why can't I use a block size other than 128 in AES?".

Comment: @vcsjones No, merging the tags would not prevent asking questions that are specific to AES or that pertain to Rijndael but not AES. Similarly, there is a [tag:windows] tag, and many of the questions in this tag do not apply to every version from Windows 1 to Windows 8.